# How to remove friend's HomePod from audio selection during phone calls?

Tags: iphone, call, homepod

I do not see it in Bluetooth devices. It is not manageable in the Home app. It's surprising how much of annoyance an extra click to get speakerphone is. Example below (NIST time of day phone number).

[image: the phone screen with the audio drop down open showing the options; iPhone, Speaker, Bathroom HomePod]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can be removed by rebooting your phone.